# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called when compiled with xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

In my app I have a popup with a [table view][1] .

When compiled with Xcode 5.1 everything works fine, but the same code compiled with Xcode 6.1 failed to call the [`cellForRowAtIndexPath`][3] [`delegate`][4] method.

The other delegate meths are called.

One intersting point is `self.tableView.rowHeight;` returns -1

I have tried explicitly setting the delegate and data source to self but that makes not difference

The class is called by the following code;

```
`-(IBAction)selectLanguage:(id)sender
{
    ATLMLanguagePopoverTableViewController *pvc = [[ATLMLanguagePopoverTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    pvc.target = self;
    pvc.action = @selector(popoverDidSelectItem:);
    pvc.items = [[[ATLMLibraryManager getManager]libraryDefaults]getAvailableLanguageNames];
    _myPopoverController.contentViewController = pvc;
    [_myPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:[pvc popoverContentSize]];
    [_myPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES]; 
}
`
```

Hear is the definition of the class

```
/
```

/  LanguagePopoverTableViewController.m
//  SalesAid
//
//  Created by phuang on 1/16/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Align Technology. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ATLMLanguagePopoverTableViewController.h"
#import "ATLMLocalizationManager.h"
#import "ATLMUtils.h"

@interface ATLMLanguagePopoverTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ATLMLanguagePopoverTableViewController
@synthesize items, selectedItem, target, action;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        selectedItem = -1;
        target = nil;
        action = NULL;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) resetLocalization {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)newItems {
    items = [newItems copy];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];



    selectedItem=0;
    NSString *curLang = (NSString *) [[ATLMLocalizationManager getManager]getCurrentLanguage]  ;
    for(int i = 0; i < items.count ; i++ ){
        if([curLang isEqualToString:(NSString *)[items objectAtIndex:i]]){
            selectedItem = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    NSIndexPath *i = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedItem inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:i animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (CGSize)popoverContentSize {
    NSInteger rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
    UITableView *tv = self.tableView;
    rowHeight = 50;
    return CGSizeMake(100, [items count] * rowHeight);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    myBackView.backgroundColor = [ATLMUtils getAlignBlue];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView: myBackView ];



    NSString *textLabelKey = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
    cell.textLabel.text = ATLMLocalizedString(textLabelKey, nil);
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedItem = indexPath.row;
    if (target != nil && action != NULL) {
        [target performSelector:action withObject:self];
    }
}
@end

`

Comment: Do the other `dataSource` methods get called (`numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection`)?

Comment: No code, no debug information, nothing, expect a lot of downvotes - probably closing votes

Comment: @maddy Yes the other delegate methods are called as expected.

Answer (score 0):

OK to answer my own question;

Basically the code adds the model to the view controller after the init method is called.  However is seem the thread model has changed a bit and the view is created before the model is added so the row count in the model is zero

The solution is to pass the model as part of the init method.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil items:(NSArray *)itemArray
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        items = [itemArray copy];
        selectedItem = -1;
        target = nil;
        action = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```